# Given a Class<?>, can I determine if it subclasses a particular type?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a Java function that takes a `Class<?>` and returns a string which represents a reasonable guess at the corresponding JavaScript type. Example input/output:

```
   in              |  out
---------------------------------
 String.class      |  "string"
 int.class         |  "number"
 double.class      |  "number"
 Integer.class     |  "number"
 Date.class        |  "date"    (yes, I know that typeof new Date() === 'object')
 boolean.class     |  "boolean"
 Foo.class         |  "object"
```

Here's what I've got so far, and it seems to mostly work:

```
String jsType(Class<?> clazz)
{
    if (clazz.equals(String.class) return "string";

    if (clazz.equals(boolean.class) return "boolean";

    try
    {
        clazz.asSubclass(Number.class);
        return "number";
    }
    catch (Exception e){}

    try
    {
        clazz.asSubclass(Date.class);
        return "date";
    }
    catch (Exception e){}

    return "object";
}
```

However, it does not correctly return "number" for number primitives, e.g. `int.class`, `double.class`, etc., though it does work correctly for the wrapper types, `Integer.class` et al.

- Is there something special about the class literals for primitive types?
- Is there a way to write this function that's **better** than a bunch of `if-else` statements, for every class I'm interested in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two questions. For the first, the answer is that there is nothing special about the class literals for primitive types, other than the obvious: that they represent primitive types. The "isPrimitive()" method will return true for such types. You seem to be expecting that the primitive "class" types are subclasses of `Number`, but that is not the case, as your example shows.

Is there a better way to write the function than a bunch of if-else statements? probably not! Although I would try to avoid using exceptions as a test, exceptions should be reserved for truly exceptional conditions; use `isAssignableFrom(Class<?>)` instead - though I guess that's more a matter of style (and perhaps efficiency).

Comment: +1, `isAssignableFrom()` is definitely an improvement. I'm still curious to know _why_ `Number.class.isAssignableFrom(int.class)` returns `false` - it's got to be because `int` is primitive.

Comment: @Matt int, being a primitive type, is not part of the Object type hierarchy. Thus, it can't be above or below anything that is (such as number).

Comment: @ILMTitan: good point. Do you have any suggestions for a non-specific way of handling these, then? e.g., something other than a bunch of `if-else` statements

Comment: @Matt, you could coalesce the checks for primitive numeric types by just checking `isPrimitive()`, after first making sure that the type isn't `boolean`. For non-primitive types you could use a hashmap to map from java class names to javascript types, if you really wanted to. I don't think you can avoid if-then-else altogether though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that normalises classes first, simplifying the `jsType` method:

```
Class<?> normalise(Class<?> cls) {
    if (Number.class.isAssignableFrom(cls) ||
        cls == int.class || cls == long.class || 
        cls == double.class || cls == float.class) {
        return Number.class;
    } else if (cls == Boolean.class || cls == boolean.class) {
        return Boolean.class;
    } else if (Date.class.isAssignableFrom(cls)) {
        return Date.class;
    } else {
        return cls;
    }
}

String jsType(Class<?> cls) {
    Class<?> normalised = normalise(cls);
    if (normalised == Number.class) {
        return "number";
    } else if (normalised == Boolean.class) {
        return "boolean";
    } else if (normalised == Date.class) {
        return "date";
    } else if (normalised == String.class) {
        return "string";
    } else {
        return "object";
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems pretty good. Are you sure that I can use `==` rather than `.equals()` on class literals?

Comment: You could of course combine the two methods too. That might be easiest.

Comment: Yes you can consider it safe to use == for instances of Class.  It is part of the specification that there is only ever one instance of any given Class object per Classloader.  (and it doesn't override the default equals() anyway, so that's all you're getting to begin with.)

Comment: @Affe: thank you for the clarification. I'm not used to working with class literals (which are instances of `Class`?).

Comment: Yes, Date.class == new Date().getClass() is a true statement, to put it simply :)